# what is pine country?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, expressions

What is **pine country** as used in the following sentence:

> The choice was limited. To go north into the empty **pine country**
>   and shoot myself, or to go south in the faint hope that a bunch of
>   strangers might help me with my drinking problem.

Source: [THE MAN WHO MASTERED FEAR](http://silkworth.net/bbstories/2nd/275_286.html)

Comment: Pine country is country covered with pine forests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general **pine country** is where **pine** or **evergeen** trees grow and is different than where broad leaf or **deciduous trees** grow.  The climate for pine trees tends to be colder and drier and therefore **less inhabited**.  The **needles** stay on the tree year round since the **small leaves** and **waxy coating** restricts **evaporation** during dry winters.  Deciduous trees will drop their leaves before winter.

The writer is referring to an **area** which is more **desolate** and **harsher** and **colder** (further north), painting a **morbid scene** in which to kill oneself.  The passage takes place in Akron, OH. The native trees of Ohio are deciduous, so the author is probably talking about travelling much further north, maybe into Michigan or further into Canada.

**Pine trees** can also be found naturally in southern areas for example [Georgia Pines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinus_palustris) but they are much taller then their northern cousins.

Tree environment is also distinguished by mountain **elevation** where **evergreens** will be the only trees to grow above the **snow line**.